# How can I move chinese characters in a string to the end of string?

Tags: php, oop, preg-replace

I have a string like this now: I want to do the following in PHP:

`$string = 'Testing giving dancing 喝 喝 passing 制图 giving 跑步 吃';`

I want to move all Chinese characters to the end of the string, and also reversing their current order. Accordingly, Removing the duplicate English words and Return the modified string

Comment: Could you please provide what you did so far, we will not write all the code for you, even for Christmas ! ;)

Comment: You have not created a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! Check the comments in the code:

```
<?php

$string = 'Testing giving dancing 喝 喝 passing 制图 giving 跑步 吃';

// split by a space into an array
$explosion = explode(' ', $string);

$normalWords = [];
$chineseWords = [];

// loop through the array
foreach ($explosion as $debris) {

   // if not normal alphabet characters
   if (!preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]+#', $debris) && !in_array($debris, $chineseWords)) {
       // add to chinese words array if not already in the array
      $chineseWords[] = $debris;
   } elseif (preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]+#', $debris) && !in_array($debris, $normalWords)) {
        // add to normal words array if not already in the array
       $normalWords[] = $debris;
   }
}

// reverse the chinese characters like you wanted
$chineseWords = array_reverse($chineseWords);

// Piece it all back together
$string = implode(' ', $normalWords) . ' ' . implode(' ', $chineseWords);

// and output
echo $string;  // Testing giving dancing passing 吃 跑步 制图 喝
```

See it here! https://3v4l.org/FWQWG